# Move MYSQL data from a dead server to a new server

Tags: mysql

I know before I even start that BACKUPs are essential but I don't have them so here is the question.  I have several mysql databases that were running on an odroid hc2.  I can no longer get the mysql server running on that.  I do have the files on an sd card and I want to put them in a mysql database on another server.  Is this even possible?  If so how do I go about it.

Yes I have since backed up all of my other databases.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: do you know what version of mysql you were running?  do keep your backup of the files safe, but you are likely able to just copy the files, restart (or install) a new version of mysql, and have it work.  if you use 5.7 or earlier you will need to run the mysql_upgrade process

Comment: after trying just about everything I can find I still can't get mysql server running again.  I am running ubuntu 20.04 on an odroid hc2.  I have tried to uninstall and reinstall with no improvement.

Comment: What *does* happen?

Comment: with phpmyadmin i get :Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory.  with mysql -u root: i get :ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'